# UICollectionView snap to 0,0 - scroll past bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've got a horizontal collection view.  Essentially the first displayed item is the "active" item.  And swiping over snaps to each item.

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to scroll the very last item to snap all the way to the front.  Currently when dragging towards the end, it doesn't snap to the first cell anymore.

Sorry if I'm not making any sense.  Essentially every cell's left most frame should snap to 0,0 of collectionView.  Which currently works perfectly for the first 2 cells.  But after that it hits the bounds and doesn't allow it to snap.  I want to be able to drag over and the final cell snap to 0,0

Thank you!

See problem here:

[image]

Here's my layout subclass:

```
class UserFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        scrollDirection = .horizontal
        itemSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 90)
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 15.0
        minimumLineSpacing = 15.0
    }

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity) }

        var offsetAdjustment = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        let horizontalOffset = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionView.contentInset.left

        let targetRect = CGRect(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: 0, width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)

        let layoutAttributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect)

        layoutAttributesArray?.forEach({ (layoutAttributes) in
            let itemOffset = layoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
            if fabsf(Float(itemOffset - horizontalOffset)) < fabsf(Float(offsetAdjustment)) {
                offsetAdjustment = itemOffset - horizontalOffset
            }
        })

        return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it's trying to scroll further to the right than it can. You need to widen your scroll view to include empty space on the right.

Your current screen width seems to be 4 cells + X, so you need that + X of empty space after your last cell.